# Not Show Image File in Fresco

Tags: android, image, mobile, local, fresco

I use the Fresco library on android, but I do not show any image that I have from my phone.

> in Xml

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/imgFile"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />
```

> First piece of code

```
imgFile.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File("file:///mnt/sdcard/Download/file.jpg")));
```

> The second piece of code

```
holder.imgFile.setImageURI(Uri.parse("mnt/sdcard/Download/file.jpg"));
```

> The third piece of code

```
holder.imgFile.setImageURI(Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/Download/file.jpg"));
```

> The fourth piece of code

```
imgFile.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File("file:///mnt/sdcard/Download/file.jpg")));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every device does not have same directory hierarchy as `mnt/sdcard/` , it could be `0/mnt/sdcard/` and similar so never hard code these values.

Instead if you want to access `Download` folder then use [File getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (String type)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) to access **public directories only** 
 so use

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
imgFile.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(path, "file.jpg")));
```

Note : Make sure you have the required permissions as well as [runtime permissions for android M and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)